# azure web app multiple instances confusion

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an web app which has 2 instances as default and from resource explorer, I can see there are two instances.
However, in global.asax code I have this code:

```
public class LogEntity : TableEntity
    {
        public LogEntity(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
        {
            this.PartitionKey = partitionKey;
            this.RowKey = rowKey;
        }
        public LogEntity() { }
        public string Submitter { get; set; }
    }

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Random ran = new Random();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]);
        var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("logs");
        table.CreateIfNotExists();

        var key1 = ran.Next();
        var machineName1 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID");

        LogEntity log1 = new LogEntity(Environment.MachineName + ":" + machineName1 + ":" + key1.ToString(), "instance started");
        TableBatchOperation batchOperation1 = new TableBatchOperation();
        batchOperation1.Insert(log1);
        table.ExecuteBatch(batchOperation1);

    }
}
```

However, from my azure table log, I can only see one log entry generated, and it is always from the same instance.

Does this mean when I have multiple instances, only one instance will call application_start? I thought all instances should hit application_start as they run independently. However, my log seems contradict my understanding.

**UPDATE**

I showed the code that logs to azure table. My expection is that as there are two instances, I should see two log entries created in the azure table. However, there is always just one entry.

Comment: Can you share the code that you're executing at the time of application startup? Please update your question with code.

Comment: Thanks! What's the PartitionKey/RowKey for the entity you're trying to insert? I don't see that in your code. It would also help if you can include the code for `LogEntity` as well.

Comment: the partitionKey key contains the instance id and machine name, so should give me different entries for different instances

Comment: `the partitionKey key contains the instance id and machine name, so should give me different entries for different instances` ==> This sounds right.

Comment: will be interested to see if you get different results, or it is just me.

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: just read my code and create a azure app with two instances

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had some discussion with Microsoft support and understands why now.

For my site, I got ARR Affinity on, with that setting on, azure load balancer will only enable the ones that have been accessed (as Affinity cookie). As a result, I only see my code run once.

When I disable Affinity, azure load balancer will enable all instances at once and I see my code run on all instances.