# Azure WebApp Flask App Scale Out - Concurrent Requests

Tags: azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I am testing whether Flask API app within Azure can handle concurrent requests. I thought the obvious way to do this was add a couple more instances to a simple test project and test whether calling the endpoint quickly would create concurrent requests, but it appears that each request is handled one at a time. My app is very simple:

```
from flask import Flask
import logging, sys
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
logger.addHandler(handler)

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def health_check(): 
    logger.info('Test Start')
    time.sleep(10)
    logger.info('Test Complete')  
    return 'Completed'
```

I then deployed to Azure WebApp and set instances to 2. I tested by opening two Edge tabs and making requests at the same time. I was hoping my logs would look like:

10:00 Test Start
10:00 Test Start
10:10 Test Complete
10:10 Test Complete

but logs in Azure show:

10:00 Test Start
10:10 Test Complete
10:10 Test Start
10:20 Test Complete

I thought increasing instances basically creates a copy of your app and Azure manages the load balancing automatically, so i would have thought that the second request would realise the first one is blocking and go to the 2nd instance?

Comment: even though the first one is doing io, the first instance still can serve requests. You need way more requests in order to proper test this. Take a look on tools to enable load testing such as JMeter or using your favorite programming languange

Answer (score 0):

In your app service ARR Affinity on, azure load balancer will only enable the only one Instances of web app. When you disable ARR Affinity, azure load balancer will enable all instances at once and you can see all instances logs. Check  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693635/azure-web-app-multiple-instances-confusion)

Refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/scaling-up-and-scaling-out-in-windows-azure-web-sites/) for more information

Comment: Thanks for your answer however ARR affinity was already off.